# Only available via iframe

Tags: iframe

Is there a way of making a webpage only available through an iframe? Basically if you go directly to the iframe source you wouldn't be able to see the content, but if you view the site through an iframe you *would* be able to see the content.

A jQuery or Javascript solution would be perfect, and I *do* have to power to edit the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding this in head of your webpage

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 if (top === self) { 
 alert('Sorry ! WebPage is only accesible via iframe')  //if current window is topmost window
  window.close();
 } else {
 alert('Well Done'); 
 }
 </script>
```

`self` means current window and `top` means browser's topmost window

Comment: The alert shows up when I visit the source directly and doesn't show up in the iframe, which is correct, but when I click OK, it just takes me to the page like normal.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! But one last thing, is there a way of it not showing the alert and just redirecting automatically?

Comment: just remove the alert line ! `window.close()` will close the tab and  `window.location.href` will redirect